# XeLaTeX - how to put accents within this preamble?

Tags: xetex, accents, preamble

I am writing some notes for a dyslexic person and am forced to do it in a sans-serif font. The person in question chose Verdana as the most readable font. Here's the preamble of my file:

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=text-text}
\setsansfont{Verdana}
\setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){Verdana}
\setmathrm{Verdana}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\geometry{letterpaper} 

\begin{document}

é

\end{document}
```

This requres XeLaTeX as typesetting engine. The problem is that I have no clue on how to get accents (è,é,ò,à) working. Any help?

Comment: Hmm.... Works for me on macOS Sierra with TeXLive 2016. Maybe post a picture of what you're seeing?

Comment: I get a small square instead of the accented character. I am working with TeXShop on Yosemite.

Comment: You have nothing to do. It should work out of the box – at least for text.

Comment: You may have something wrong with your installation, then. This should just work.

Comment: Is TeXShop configured to save in `utf8` format? I believe the default is still the antediluvian MacOSRoman.

Comment: As far as I know, inputenc should not be used with XeTeX...

Comment: @marcotrevi inputenc should not be used but you need to make sure that your file is saved in UTF-8. Also although unrelated to the accents, `article` does not have a `16pt` option.

Comment: @Bernard There's no difference in the character code for é in MacOSRoman (approximately Latin-1) and utf8, I think.

Comment: é has code 8E in MacOSRoman, and E in UTF-8. As far as I know, the ASCII part is the same, but the rest is different.

Comment: Add `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` at the very beginning of the document (the exact string from `%` to `Unicode`), then save and run XeLaTeX again.

Comment: @Bernard I was wrong; I was thinking of UTF16. "é" in MacOSRoman and UTF16 is 0xE9 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman); it's 0xC3 0xA9 in UTF8. I don't know why you think its "8E" and "E", respectively.

Comment: @Derek: For UTF-8, it was a mistyping. I meant E9, of course. For Mac OS Roman, it's in all Wikipedia notices, except the English one. 0xE9 seems to be È.  (From the point of view of English speaking people, there's little difference, I guess… ;o))

Comment: @Derek they are not the same in UTF-16 either: macroman is an 8-bit encoding so  é  takes one byte, utf-16 and utf-8 are both multi-length encodings in which  é  takes two bytes (Ox00 0xE9 in utf-16)

Comment: Check the log-file. If you find a `Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence` message then your file has not the correct encoding.